# Webservice for IBM Lotus Notes to send email using C#

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Hi I need to send email from an asp.net website using IBM Lotus Notes. Is there any web service for consuming ibm lotus notes in asp.net website ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Lotus Domino does not have a native web services API that would be equivalent to Microsoft's Exchange Web Services. There are, however, numerous other APIs, including a COM API that is available in C#. There are some issues with it on 64 bit Windows, though. It can be made to work, mostly, but it's not officially supported on Win64 by IBM. A [simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23%20lotus%20) here in Stackoverflow for "C# Lotus" would not be a bad way to find some information about it.